# Ending a while loop with a specific input

Tags: python, nameerror

I have attempted to search for similar problems, but have come up short.  I'm attempting to get a while loop to stop upon the input 'done'.  No matter what I do or how I format it, it either won't stop the loop, or it prints the value I have assigned to 'done'.  If I run it without an assignment it throws a 'NameError: name 'done' is not defined'.  If I assign a value to it, it won't end the loop.  I am not asking for code optimization or help with anything else, but I would truly appreciate it if someone could explain why this is happening.

```
Counter1 = 0   
Counter2 = 0
Counter3 = 0
Counter4 = 0
n = 0
while True:  #Begins a loop that runs until manually ended.   
        n = input("Enter desired scores, and type done when complete: ")
        if n == "done":  #Closes the loop if given this input.
                break
        else:
                n = int(n) #changes input to an integer
        if n >= 0 and n <= 25:    #increments the counters depending on the input
                Counter1 = Counter1 + 1
        elif n > 25 and n <= 50:
                Counter2 = Counter2 + 1
        elif n > 50 and n <= 75:
                Counter3 = Counter3 + 1
        else:
                Counter4 = Counter4 + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Python 2. `input` immediately tries to convert your input into a Python type, which is **dangerous** and causes problems like the one you are experiencing. Use `raw_input` instead.

In other words, when you type "done", `input` tries to [eval](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx)* it, comes up with a non-existent variable named "done", and bails out complaining. If you use `raw_input` instead, it will give you a string, which you can properly cast into a different type as desired, or as in your case, leave it alone since a string is what you want.

* This is about JavaScript but eval appears in many programming languages.

Comment: I'm using Python 3, but apparently more incorrectly than I previously thought.

Comment: Are you certain? This is an extremely common error. I am almost positive. How are you running this?

Comment: Thank you so very much!  I couldn't understand what I needed to do for it to stop thinking that done was a variable.

Comment: It's being run in Wing101.  The raw_input corrected the issue, so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: You are certainly running Python 2. `raw_input` does not exist on Python 3.

Comment: Then I have a lot more severe problems than I thought with this question.  I definitely installed 3.4.2 on my computer.  I'm not sure why it is doing this then.

Comment: raw_input() and input() existed only in Python2 and in python3, input() was removed; raw_input() was renamed as input()

Comment: @Ridolenai Try this and find the version of Python; import sys. and sys.version_info

Comment: I'm not attempting to debate the presence of raw_input in Python 2 and not in 3, I am only stating that the package I downloaded from the Python.org website is labeled as 3.4.2.  I don't know how I ended up with Python 2 installed.

Comment: @shar Where should I try this?

Comment: Version 3.4.2 (3.4.2) that is from the Python Launcher splash page when I open it.

Comment: @Ridolenai: If you are running a Python shell, you can just type in there and check. Else, you could write a simple py script and run the script.

Comment: Does it make a difference if I am running it on a Mac?  I realize that it shouldn't, but now I'm a bit paranoid that I'm going to end up with something severely wrong because of this and I don't know why it would recognize Python 2 codes in Python 3.

Comment: @Ridolenai Which platform are you using? Mac or Windows? If you are using a mac, you could just type "python" on the terminal and that should show you the version

Comment: The installation file I used says 3.4, but terminal is telling me that it is 2.7.  If the file I downloaded from Python.org is the incorrect version, where do I go to get the correct one?

Comment: @Ridolenai: Probably, you have both python2 and python3 installed and the default symlinks to python2. Just type python3 in your terminal and check if its installed. If yes, you can change the default to python3 and try if that works out

Comment: How would I change the default symlink to point to python3 instead of 2?